# CSS DIV moving while loading

Tags: css, google-chrome, joomla, safari, opera

For some reason when I load the website in Chrome, Safari and Opera, the div container starts from the top of the website then moves into place where I positioned it. This only happens when I load the website. What exactly could be causing the DIV to be doing this? The container doesn't move in Firefox though, it loads in place as the site is loading and after its finished loading.

Is something wrong with my code?

```
    <div style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:4px;"><center><img src="images/home_banner.png" /></center></div><div style="position:relative; float:right; display:inline; margin-top:-180px; padding-top:5px; padding-right:3px;">
<div style="font-size:60px; font-family:arial narrow;padding-bottom:43px;">Starting a Business</div>
<div style="font-size:60px; font-family:arial narrow; font-weight:bold;">Now Made Easy</div>
<div style="font-size:15px;padding-top:34px;">Document Driven Solutions that Promote Business Growth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's moving cause you image is loading. It has no height or width and when it loads (gets a height) it pushes out the top div.

Comment: give your image a width="#" height="#"

Comment: Thank you so much Deach. That definitely resolved the issue!

Comment: The last decade called; they want their inline styles back. Oh, and the previous millennium is still on hold, they want to speak with you about their... "center tag"? :)

Comment: Haha very funny Mark! Thanks for the advice though guys.

Comment: margin-top: -180px; wats the use